# How does routing happen in MVC when second session is started?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have understood that the `Application_Start()` method will be called only once in the `ASP.Net`,and inside the `Application_Start()` method in MVC application we will make a call `RegisterRoutes()` where the routing table will be created.

So does that mean the routing table will be created only once when the first request reaches to the server? Or for every new request by the new user (new session) the routing table will be created?

Comment: If you place a debugging breakpoint there, start your application with the debugger, and start making requests to it, what do you observe happening?

Comment: @David I've done that and I've observed that the Application_Start() will be called only once and Session_Start() will be executed whenever the new session is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, stop learning outdated contexts. `Global.asax`, its code behind `.cs` and `Application_Start()` and other magic methods are a thing of the old .NET Framework ASP.NET 4 way of doing things. Nowadays new development and education should happen on .NET Core, see for example [Migrate from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

As for your question: the routing information is built once on startup, and then kept in memory for as long as the web application lives.